# Jboss 5.0.GA Server not starting on DEBUG mode

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I found a very strange scenario where my JBOSS server is not getting started in DEBUG mode it takes too much time and after time specified as TIMEOUTS it stops completely. Strange thing is related to sysouts on console the last item that is on console is always same which is as follows.

```
13:00:43,983 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/mdmapp
13:00:44,062 INFO  [[/mdmapp]] Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
13:00:44,062 INFO  [ContextLoader] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
13:00:44,108 INFO  [XmlWebApplicationContext] Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Dec 31 13:00:44 GMT+05:30 2012]; root of context hierarchy
13:00:44,202 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
13:00:44,233 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/vin/mdm/utility/UtilityContext.xml]
13:00:44,233 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/vin/mdm/adapter/AdapterContext.xml]
13:00:44,249 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/vin/mdm/repository/RepositoryContext.xml]
13:00:44,280 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/vin/mdm/service/ServiceContext.xml]
13:00:44,280 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/vin/mdm/web/WebContext.xml]
13:00:44,437 INFO  [DefaultListableBeanFactory] Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@28e2a0c: defining beans [hibernateMySql,entity,user,masterHier,userRepository,entityRepository,masterHierRepository,nodeVO,workFlowMaster,workFlowDetail,workflowDao,ruleEngineDao,roleRepository,roleMaster,roleInstanceMapping,roleModuleMapping,instMstDaoImpl,configDao,clientDao,config,taskScreenDAO,userDto,userManager,entityManager,masterHierManager,workflowManager,workflowDTO,nodeDTO,ruleEngineManager,ruleDto,baseRuleDto,roleManager,roleDto,codeWriterManagement,sysconfigManager,configDto,taskScreenManager,userAuth,entityAction,jsonEntityAction,userAction,jsonUserAction,ruleEngineAction,roleModuleAction,jsonRoleModuleAction,codeWriterAction,sysConfigAction,testAutoCompleter]; root of factory hierarchy
13:00:44,515 INFO  [Environment] Hibernate 3.3.1.GA
13:00:44,515 INFO  [Environment] hibernate.properties not found
13:00:44,530 INFO  [Environment] Bytecode provider name : javassist
13:00:44,530 INFO  [Environment] using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
13:00:44,624 INFO  [Configuration] configuring from resource: /com/vin/mdm/repository/hmysql.cfg.xml
13:00:44,624 INFO  [Configuration] Configuration resource: /com/vin/mdm/repository/hmysql.cfg.xml
13:00:44,640 INFO  [Configuration] Reading mappings from resource : com/vin/mdm/repository/dao/user/User.hbm.xml
13:00:44,702 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.vin.mdm.repository.dao.user.User -> user_master
13:00:44,733 INFO  [Configuration] Reading mappings from resource : com/vin/mdm/repository/dao/entity/Entity.hbm.xml
13:00:44,749 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.vin.mdm.repository.dao.entity.Entity -> entity_master
13:00:44,749 INFO  [Configuration] Reading mappings from resource : com/vin/mdm/repository/vo/ParameterMaster.hbm.xml
13:00:44,749 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.vin.mdm.repository.vo.ParameterMaster -> parameter_master
13:00:44,749 INFO  [Configuration] Reading mappings from resource : com/vin/mdm/repository/vo/RoleInstanceMapping.hbm.xml
13:00:44,749 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.vin.mdm.repository.vo.RoleInstanceMapping -> role_instance_mapping
13:00:44,827 INFO  [Configuration] Reading mappings from resource : com/vin/mdm/repository/vo/WorkflowDetail.hbm.xml
13:00:44,827 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.vin.mdm.repository.vo.WorkflowDetail -> workflow_detail
13:00:44,827 INFO  [Configuration] Reading mappings from resource : com/vin/mdm/repository/vo/RoleModuleMapping.hbm.xml
13:00:44,843 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.vin.mdm.repository.vo.RoleModuleMapping -> role_module_mapping
13:00:44,843 INFO  [Configuration] Reading mappings from resource : com/vin/mdm/repository/vo/WorkflowMaster.hbm.xml
13:00:44,843 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.vin.mdm.repository.vo.WorkflowMaster -> workflow_master
13:00:44,843 INFO  [Configuration] Reading mappings from resource : com/vin/mdm/repository/vo/ModuleMaster.hbm.xml
13:00:44,858 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.vin.mdm.repository.vo.ModuleMaster -> module_master
13:00:44,858 INFO  [Configuration] Reading mappings from resource : com/vin/mdm/repository/vo/RoleMaster.hbm.xml
13:00:44,858 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.vin.mdm.repository.vo.RoleMaster -> role_master
13:00:44,858 INFO  [Configuration] Reading mappings from resource : com/vin/mdm/repository/vo/MenuMaster.hbm.xml
13:00:44,858 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.vin.mdm.repository.vo.MenuItem -> menu_items
13:00:44,858 INFO  [Configuration] Reading mappings from resource : com/vin/mdm/repository/vo/MenuRoleMapping.hbm.xml
13:00:44,874 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.vin.mdm.repository.vo.MenuRoleMapping -> menu_role_mapping
13:00:44,874 INFO  [Configuration] Reading mappings from resource : com/vin/mdm/repository/dao/ruleEngine/InstanceMaster.hbm.xml
13:00:44,874 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.vin.mdm.repository.dao.ruleEngine.InstanceMaster -> instance_master
13:00:44,874 INFO  [Configuration] Reading mappings from resource : com/vin/mdm/repository/dao/ruleEngine/RuleDetail.hbm.xml
13:00:44,874 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.vin.mdm.repository.dao.ruleEngine.RuleDetail -> rule_detail
13:00:44,874 INFO  [Configuration] Reading mappings from resource : com/vin/mdm/repository/dao/ruleEngine/InstanceHierLevelMaster.hbm.xml
13:00:44,890 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.vin.mdm.repository.dao.ruleEngine.InstanceHierLevelMaster -> instance_hier_level_master
13:00:44,890 INFO  [Configuration] Reading mappings from resource : com/vin/mdm/repository/dao/ruleEngine/InstanceHierLevelDetail.hbm.xml
13:00:44,921 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.vin.mdm.repository.dao.ruleEngine.InstanceHierLevelDetailVO -> instance_hier_level_detail
13:00:44,921 INFO  [Configuration] Reading mappings from resource : com/vin/mdm/repository/dao/ruleEngine/ModelRuleDetail.hbm.xml
13:00:44,937 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.vin.mdm.repository.dao.ruleEngine.ModelRuleDetail -> model_rule_detail
13:00:44,937 INFO  [Configuration] Reading mappings from resource : com/vin/mdm/repository/dao/client/ClientConfiguration.hbm.xml
13:00:44,937 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.vin.mdm.repository.dao.client.ClientConfiguration -> client_master
13:00:44,937 INFO  [Configuration] Reading mappings from resource : com/vin/mdm/repository/dao/ruleEngine/FieldRuleDetail.hbm.xml
13:00:44,937 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.vin.mdm.repository.dao.ruleEngine.FieldRuleDetail -> field_detail
13:00:44,937 INFO  [Configuration] Configured SessionFactory: null
13:00:44,983 INFO  [DriverManagerConnectionProvider] Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
13:00:44,983 INFO  [DriverManagerConnectionProvider] Hibernate connection pool size: 20
13:00:44,983 INFO  [DriverManagerConnectionProvider] autocommit mode: false
13:00:44,983 INFO  [DriverManagerConnectionProvider] using driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.223:3306/mdmdb
13:00:44,983 INFO  [DriverManagerConnectionProvider] connection properties: {user=mdmuser, password=mdm123}
13:00:45,358 INFO  [SettingsFactory] RDBMS: MySQL, version: 5.5.28-enterprise-commercial-advanced
13:00:45,358 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JDBC driver: MySQL-AB JDBC Driver, version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.6 ( Revision: ${svn.Revision} )
13:00:45,390 INFO  [Dialect] Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
13:00:45,390 INFO  [TransactionFactoryFactory] Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
13:00:45,390 INFO  [TransactionManagerLookupFactory] No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
13:00:45,390 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
13:00:45,390 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
13:00:45,390 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JDBC batch size: 15
13:00:45,390 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
13:00:45,390 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Scrollable result sets: enabled
13:00:45,390 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
13:00:45,390 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Connection release mode: auto
13:00:45,405 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2
13:00:45,405 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Default batch fetch size: 1
13:00:45,405 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Generate SQL with comments: disabled
13:00:45,405 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
13:00:45,405 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
13:00:45,405 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
13:00:45,405 INFO  [ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
13:00:45,405 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Query language substitutions: {}
13:00:45,405 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
13:00:45,405 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Second-level cache: enabled
13:00:45,405 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Query cache: disabled
13:00:45,405 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory
13:00:45,405 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
13:00:45,405 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
13:00:45,405 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Echoing all SQL to stdout
13:00:45,405 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Statistics: disabled
13:00:45,405 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
13:00:45,405 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Default entity-mode: pojo
13:00:45,405 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Named query checking : enabled
13:00:45,483 INFO  [SessionFactoryImpl] building session factory
13:00:46,046 INFO  [SessionFactoryObjectFactory] Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
```

and after these lines nothing is there it just hangs and stops while in normal run mode its working fine..

Please Suggest the needful.

Here are the first 50 lines...

```
13:08:44,430 INFO  [ServerImpl] Starting JBoss (Microcontainer)...
13:08:44,446 INFO  [ServerImpl] Release ID: JBoss [Morpheus] 5.0.1.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_0_1_GA date=200902232048)
13:08:44,446 INFO  [ServerImpl] Bootstrap URL: null
13:08:44,446 INFO  [ServerImpl] Home Dir: C:\jboss-5.0.1.GA
13:08:44,446 INFO  [ServerImpl] Home URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/
13:08:44,446 INFO  [ServerImpl] Library URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/lib/
13:08:44,446 INFO  [ServerImpl] Patch URL: null
13:08:44,446 INFO  [ServerImpl] Common Base URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/common/
13:08:44,446 INFO  [ServerImpl] Common Library URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/common/lib/
13:08:44,461 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Name: default
13:08:44,461 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Base Dir: C:\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server
13:08:44,461 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Base URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/
13:08:44,461 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Config URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/conf/
13:08:44,461 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Home Dir: C:\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server\default
13:08:44,461 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Home URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/
13:08:44,461 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Data Dir: C:\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server\default\data
13:08:44,461 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Library URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/lib/
13:08:44,461 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Log Dir: C:\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server\default\log
13:08:44,461 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Native Dir: C:\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server\default\tmp\native
13:08:44,461 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Temp Dir: C:\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server\default\tmp
13:08:44,461 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Temp Deploy Dir: C:\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server\default\tmp\deploy
13:08:46,883 INFO  [ServerImpl] Starting Microcontainer, bootstrapURL=file:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/conf/bootstrap.xml
13:08:49,430 INFO  [VFSCacheFactory] Initializing VFSCache [org.jboss.virtual.plugins.cache.CombinedVFSCache]
13:08:49,430 INFO  [VFSCacheFactory] Using VFSCache [CombinedVFSCache[real-cache: null]]
13:08:49,680 INFO  [CopyMechanism] VFS temp dir: C:\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server\default\tmp
13:08:49,695 INFO  [ZipEntryContext] VFS force nested jars copy-mode is enabled.
13:08:52,102 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.6.0_20,Oracle Corporation
13:08:52,102 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
13:08:52,102 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Oracle JRockit(R) R28.1.0-123-138454-1.6.0_20-20101014-1351-windows-ia32,Oracle Corporation
13:08:52,102 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Windows XP 5.1,x86
13:08:52,117 INFO  [JMXKernel] Legacy JMX core initialized
13:08:54,633 INFO  [ProfileServiceImpl] Loading profile: default from: org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.SerializableDeploymentRepository@23fc3d8(root=C:\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server, key=org.jboss.profileservice.spi.ProfileKey@143b82c3[domain=default,server=default,name=default])
13:08:54,633 INFO  [ProfileImpl] Using repository:org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.SerializableDeploymentRepository@23fc3d8(root=C:\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server, key=org.jboss.profileservice.spi.ProfileKey@143b82c3[domain=default,server=default,name=default])
13:08:54,633 INFO  [ProfileServiceImpl] Loaded profile: ProfileImpl@24ce5f4{key=org.jboss.profileservice.spi.ProfileKey@143b82c3[domain=default,server=default,name=default]}
13:09:01,507 INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase: http://localhost:8083/
13:09:11,991 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] JBoss Web Services - Stack Native Core
13:09:11,991 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] 3.0.5.GA
13:09:34,366 INFO  [JMXConnectorServerService] JMX Connector server: service:jmx:rmi://localhost/jndi/rmi://localhost:1090/jmxconnector
13:09:34,584 INFO  [MailService] Mail Service bound to java:/Mail
13:09:36,584 WARN  [JBossASSecurityMetadataStore] WARNING! POTENTIAL SECURITY RISK. It has been detected that the MessageSucker component which sucks messages from one node to another has not had its password changed from the installation default. Please see the JBoss Messaging user guide for instructions on how to do this.
13:09:36,600 WARN  [AnnotationCreator] No ClassLoader provided, using TCCL: org.jboss.managed.api.annotation.ManagementComponent
13:09:36,850 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] JBossTS Transaction Service (JTA version) - JBoss Inc.
13:09:36,850 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Setting up property manager MBean and JMX layer
13:09:37,334 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Initializing recovery manager
13:09:37,709 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Recovery manager configured
13:09:37,709 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Binding TransactionManager JNDI Reference
13:09:37,725 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Starting transaction recovery manager
13:09:38,647 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080
13:09:38,647 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8009
13:09:38,647 INFO  [StandardService] Starting service jboss.web
13:09:38,647 INFO  [StandardEngine] Starting Servlet Engine: JBoss Web/2.1.2.GA
13:09:38,694 INFO  [Catalina] Server startup in 114 ms
13:09:38,725 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/web-console
13:09:40,522 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/invoker
13:09:40,615 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/jbossws
13:09:40,756 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/jboss-local-jdbc.rar/META-INF/ra.xml
13:09:40,772 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/jboss-xa-jdbc.rar/META-INF/ra.xml
13:09:40,787 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/jms-ra.rar/META-INF/ra.xml
13:09:40,818 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/mail-ra.rar/META-INF/ra.xml
13:09:40,865 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/quartz-ra.rar/META-INF/ra.xml
13:09:41,022 INFO  [SimpleThreadPool] Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: main
13:09:41,053 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Quartz Scheduler v.1.5.2 created.
13:09:41,053 INFO  [RAMJobStore] RAMJobStore initialized.
13:09:41,053 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
13:09:41,053 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler version: 1.5.2
13:09:41,053 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
13:09:41,318 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=VDSS-DS' to JNDI name 'java:VDSS-DS'
13:09:41,428 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=VinMetro' to JNDI name 'java:VinMetro'
13:09:41,475 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=VinMDM-DS' to JNDI name 'java:VinMDM-DS'
13:09:41,568 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=VinMMS-DS' to JNDI name 'java:VinMMS-DS'
13:09:44,146 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=DefaultDS' to JNDI name 'java:DefaultDS'
13:09:44,975 INFO  [ServerPeer] JBoss Messaging 1.4.1.GA server [0] started
13:09:45,193 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] Connector bisocket://localhost:4457 has leasing enabled, lease period 10000 milliseconds
13:09:45,193 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] org.jboss.jms.server.connectionfactory.ConnectionFactory@3f1bbb4 started
13:09:45,240 INFO  [QueueService] Queue[/queue/ExpiryQueue] started, fullSize=200000, pageSize=2000, downCacheSize=2000
13:09:45,240 WARN  [ConnectionFactoryJNDIMapper] supportsFailover attribute is true on connection factory: jboss.messaging.connectionfactory:service=ClusteredConnectionFactory but post office is non clustered. So connection factory will *not* support failover
13:09:45,240 WARN  [ConnectionFactoryJNDIMapper] supportsLoadBalancing attribute is true on connection factory: jboss.messaging.connectionfactory:service=ClusteredConnectionFactory but post office is non clustered. So connection factory will *not* support load balancing
13:09:45,240 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] Connector bisocket://localhost:4457 has leasing enabled, lease period 10000 milliseconds
13:09:45,240 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] org.jboss.jms.server.connectionfactory.ConnectionFactory@3ef1969 started
13:09:45,240 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] Connector bisocket://localhost:4457 has leasing enabled, lease period 10000 milliseconds
13:09:45,240 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] org.jboss.jms.server.connectionfactory.ConnectionFactory@3ef1985 started
13:09:45,240 INFO  [QueueService] Queue[/queue/DLQ] started, fullSize=200000, pageSize=2000, downCacheSize=2000
13:09:45,803 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=ConnectionFactoryBinding,name=JmsXA' to JNDI name 'java:JmsXA'
13:09:45,834 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/
13:09:45,912 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/jmx-console
13:09:46,006 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/mdmapp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the log there was no problem in Server or any type of configuration the actual problem was with Hibernate Module which was getting loaded during server bootstrap. So after removing the error related to Hibernate server started normally.

Answer (score 0):

hey  post your starting log (First 50 lines) .

*Post your JAVA_OPTS

try this if you are running server from command line and using linux :-

**export JAVA_OPTS='-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8789,server=y,suspend=n'**

then Run server from same console

or

you can set JAVA_OPTS in run.sh/run.bat as 
**JAVA_OPTS='-Xdebug -unjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8789,server=y,suspend=n'**

Comment: see this i tried in my system then in log debug port(8789) is opened try to change port no.:                                                            **Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8789**
18:36:19,848 INFO  [Server] Starting JBoss (MX MicroKernel)...

Comment: JAVA_OPTS: -Dprogram.name=run.bat -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000

Comment: In your JAVA_OPTS we couldn't see **-XDebug** that is use for enable debugging look at this [link](http://oreilly.com/java/archive/eclipse-jboss-remote-debug.html?page=6)

Comment: Thanks for you reply... but the problem has been resolved there was some Hibernate Related Problem now its working fine.